# Select data from Mysql db and display it android

Tags: php, android

I have an android app that shows me a map, my location and several markers which stands for bus stations and all I want is to be able to display the schedule of selected buses from the selected marker (station) in a list view ([something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTLV8.png) ). Any idea on how to do that? I also need a php script for that if you could help me.

Below is my MapActivity:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    String JSON_STRING;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LatLng mLatLng;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        new MarkerTask().execute();

    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().isCompassEnabled();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
       // Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {

            mLatLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(mLatLng)
                    .zoom(18)
                    .tilt(75)
                    .bearing(20)
                    .build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }




    class MarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://some address.php");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                }


                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;

        }
            // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute (String result){

                JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    LatLng latLng = null;
                    try {
                        latLng = new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // Create a marker for each station in the JSON data.
                    try {
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                                .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                                .position(latLng));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I want to mention that I have a DB in MySQL with 3 tables :

1) Station (station_id,name, lat, lng);

2) Bus (bus_id, bus_no);

3) Schedule (bus_id, station_id, hour).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would recommend checking out this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve data from the `mysql` database, you need to create a simple `REST API`. [Here](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/) is a tutorial about how to create a simple `REST API` using `PHP`.

After the `API` creation, you'll be fetching the data from the `Android` side. See this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/)

If you've any more question,feel free to ask.